# Basic question about Ideals in Commutative Rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $\mathcal{I}, \mathcal{J}$ be ideals of the commutative ring $\mathcal{A}$.
It's a well know fact that:

$\mathcal{I} + \mathcal{J}= A \Rightarrow \mathcal{I} \mathcal{J} = \mathcal{I} \cap \mathcal{J} $.

What can I say about the vice versa?

Comment: Could you have something like $\mathcal{I}=(0)$, and $\mathcal{J}$ a proper ideal of $A$?

Comment: I've added the comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case where $\mathcal{I}=(0)$ and $\mathcal{J}$ is a proper ideal of $\mathcal{A}$.

Then $\mathcal{IJ}=\mathcal{I}\cap\mathcal{J}=(0)$, but $\mathcal{I}+\mathcal{J}=\mathcal{J}\neq\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

in $\mathbf Z[x_1,x_2,x_3]$ consider the ideals $(x_1)$ and $(x_2)$

Comment: let me know if you got it

Comment: Noomi's idea was already enough.